# Check whether symbol NaN is a string or a python reserved symbol for missing value

Tags: python, python-import

I read a big csv file in python. There is no descriptions about the data set and how the missing value is coded.

If I want to replace all missing values by 0, I think I can use function `fillna()`. However, my question is: I think this function `fillna()` and may be other functions operating on missing values can recognize a missing value only if the symbol `NaN` in the dataframe is the python reserved symbol right? If `NaN` is a string, i.e., `"NaN"`, then the function `fillna()` would not able to detect that right?

I did an experiment

```
import numpy as np
a = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,'NaN'], 'b':['NaN',1,np.nan]})
a.fillna("")
```

Here I try to replace missing value by blank. But as you can see, this `fillna()` function only catches the `np.nan` but could not recognize the string `"NaN"` as missing value. This is understandable.

Here are my questions: how really does the function `read_csv` or other importing functions in python work (I mean encode) to handle missing value from the raw data? When these importing functions reading csv or txt files (or other format) if they "see" what symbol in the raw data set, will they automatically using a reserved symbol `NaN` to replace that piece of raw data? For example, when they are reading raw data, if they saw a blank, or saw a symbol like "\N", what they will do? I guess if they see "\N", they will just make this symbol into a string, right? But if they see a blank, what will they do?

Second question: as in my data set, it is possible to have multiple symbol to denote missing value, for example, a python reserved symbol `NaN` (automatically generated when reading raw data) represents missing value; the string `"\N"` also represents missing value; a blank also represents missing value. So I need to write a function to transform all these different kinds of missing value symbol into one, i.e., the python reserved symbol `NaN`. I did the following

```
def nullify(x):
    if x == "\\N":
        return "NaN"
    else:
        return x
```

Then I find that I have a bunch of `"NaN"` string rather than the python reserved symbol `NaN`, which makes functions like `fillna()` fails to catch that. I wonder if the correct way to write this `nullify()` is

```
import numpy as np
def nullify(x):
    if x == "\\N":
        return np.nan
    else:
        return x
```

It is the first time I start to play around with real world raw data, many interesting things start to appear. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pandas.read_csv()` takes a keyword argument `na_values`.  To quote the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> na_values : scalar, str, list-like, or dict, default None Additional
>   strings to recognize as NA/NaN. If dict passed, specific per-column NA
>   values. By default the following values are interpreted as NaN: ‘’,
>   ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’,
>   ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘nan’`.

Adding all the types of NaNs in your dataset to `na_values` when reading in the CSV will convert them all to a single type of `nan`, so you don't need to resort to manually converting them.